# Notebook Description in Evernote?

Tags: evernote

In Evernote, is it possible to add description to a Notebook? I have looked around but did not find anything.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no description for Notebooks in Evernote at this time. The functionality is fairly simple, you can create groups of notebooks ([Stacks](https://support.evernote.com/ics/support/KBAnswer.asp?questionID=622&docID=24002)) but that is about it. Stacks don't have descriptions either.

Answer (score 0):

The name of the notebook is where you describe it.

Notebooks are a feature to collect related notes in one place to quickly find them.

The relation should be obvious, best if we can put it down in one word or phrase. E.g. project XYZ, or the month of July 2021, etc.

One can use ***naming conventions*** for notebooks to identify them easily. Like every notebook could have a prefix of the business function it deals with. E.g.

---

- Mrkt:Content
- Mrkt:Advertisement
- Mrkt:PPC
- Mrkt:Budgets

---

- Fin:Investments
- Fin:Receivables
- Fin:Loanbook

---

.. etc.